# Python pandas statistics

Tags: python, pandas

```
         user_id  report_date  tBalance  yBalance  total_purchase_amt  
0              3     20131106         0         0                   0   
1              4     20140726         0         0             5119808   
2              5     20131029       153       153                   0   
3              5     20141101    196254    196229                  25   
4              5     20141104    196329    196304                  25   
5              5     20131107    179600    179577                  23   
6              5     20131110    159834    159814                  20
```

a sample of my data, I want to find out the entry of new users of every month.for example, users 3  first appeared at 2013011 and they didn't appeared before.then I want this entry

```
user_id  report_date  tBalance  yBalance       total_purchase_amt  
   3     20131106         0         0              0
```

Comment: what does `total_purchase_amt daily of May` mean here? Are you just wanting the first occurence of each user, your question is a little unclear

Comment: a statistics of new users every month,find out the new users of every month

Comment: I don't know how to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, the entry you want would have 2013011 (instead of 20131106) as report_date? And you would like this line for every month?

If so, I would simply take the first occurence month for each user:

1. Convert report_date to a date format and keep only the month (and year), let's call it report_date_month
2. Create a data frame associating, for each user, the first date it appears in your table:

   ```
   df2 = df[['user_id','report_date_month']].groupby('user_id').min()
   ```
3. Reset the index to access your groups (user_id):

   ```
   df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
   ```
4. Group by month and count the number of users:

   ```
   df2.groupby('report_date_month').count()
   ```

This will give you a 2-column data frame containing, for each month, the number of users that appeared this month

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your question. In this example I use masks to get a Series of users logged in a particular month and a Series of users logged all the other months.
I then compare the two Series and pick the users present only in the first one.

In this example I build a pandas.Dataframe from a tab delimited file 'input.txt' where I have copied your input.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_table('input.txt').astype(int)
target_month = 20131100 #yyyymmdd the month starts at day 00

mask_1 = df.report_date > target_month
mask_2 = df.report_date < (target_month + 100) #adding 100 changes the month

subset_1 = df[mask_1 & mask_2].groupby(['user_id']) # all users showed up during the target month


mask_3 = df.report_date < target_month
mask_4 = df.report_date > (target_month + 100)

subset_2 = df[mask_3 | mask_4].groupby(['user_id']) # all users showed up in other months


new_users = []
for item in subset_1['user_id']:
    for user in list(item[1]):
        if user not in new_users:
            new_users += [user]

for item in subset_2['user_id']:
    for user in list(item[1]):
        if user in new_users:
            new_users.remove(user)

output = df[df.user_id.isin(new_users)]
print(output)
```

The output is:

```
         user_id  report_date  tBalance  yBalance  total_purchase_amt  
0              3     20131106         0         0                   0
```